Create a type with one generic and one optional argument keeping the inferring ability
Given the following function declaration:
export function createStyleSheet<S extends StyleSheet>(stylesheet: S) {}

I want to add a second argument but keep the S inferring from the first parameter, is it possible? I was thinking in something like:
export function createStyleSheet<P, S extends StyleSheet>(stylesheet: S) {}

But when I try to use it, it says that the function requires 2 arguments instead of one, also, I'm not sure it will still infer from the first parameter:

Why do I need this? The createStyleSheet function returns an object with many other functions that it creates, one of these functions are the createSelector, and, instead of declaring these functions with one argument, something like function createSelector<P>() {}, I want to receive it once in the main function createStyleSheet, so, instead of this:
export function createStyleSheet<S extends StyleSheet>(stylesheet: S) {
  function createSelector<P>() {}
  function createSomething<P>() {}
  function createAnotherThing<P>() {}
  function createAnyThing<P>() {}
}

I want this, where the argument P is optional:
export function createStyleSheet<P, S extends StyleSheet>(stylesheet: S) {
  function createSelector() {}
  function createSomething() {}
  function createAnotherThing() {}
  function createAnyThing() {}
}

Does it makes sense? I really appreciate your help.

There's a kind of dumb workaround here which is to break it into two curried functions.
export function createComponentStyleSheet<P>() {
    return function <S extends StyleSheet>(stylesheet: S) {
        return createStyleSheet<P, S>(stylesheet);
    };
}

Then you can call
createComponentStyleSheet<ButtonProps>()(yourStyleSheet)

Notice that there is an extra set of empty parentheses () for the added function call.  All that the first function does is to return a wrapped version of createStyleSheet which is aware that P is ButtonProps.
